# React - how to access result of autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I followed this [tutorial](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/) for Autocomplete function, code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8pn97y064?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js). It is working fine, but I would like to access the result of the suggestion in the App.js so I could use the result for search or any other feature. Any idea how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass down a function as a prop, so that you can pass the value to that function and use it in the parent. I modified your example if you want to try it out [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-brattain-g4v6s?file=/src/App.js)